# Is is possible to do a query on another SQL server from one server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

is it possible to do something like

```
select * from [anotherserver].somedatabase.dbo.employee
```

[anotherserver] is on same network as my current SQL server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes with linked servers see [Linking Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) on MSDN and also this article on how to use [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In sqlServer you can do :

```
SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET(
           'SQLOLEDB',
           'Server=yourServer;Uid=yourID;Pwd=yourPWD;Database=yourDB',
           'select somfield1,somefield2 from yourTable'
       ) AS alias
```

But you got to be really carefull with the quote character ( ' ), be sure you have a correct string.